# Using non-npm packages with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-encore

i want to use some packages which are not on npm, but my application is using npm and webpack for bundling, how can i use those packages in my application. These packages does not have package.json file.

I do not want to use separate script tags for including them in my webpage, instead i want npm and webpack to bundle them with my other code.
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you share which specific non-npm packages. Is it pubicly hosted or are these packages that is internally used in your project/company

Comment: Like this one https://unitegallery.net/ or this one https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-wizards/ there are many more

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download your packages into your project. Say,

`src/vendor/colorlib` is your directory:

```
// src/vendor/colorlib
import './../vendor/colorlib';
```

Change `webpack.config.js` to include your vendor library

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

// web.config.js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor')
  }
},

// src/foo.js
import 'vendor/colorlib';
```